# How much heat is exchanged by this system?

Tags: combustion

I am having trouble with the following question:

We allow $\pu{18 g}$ of oxygen to react with $\pu{23 g}$ of ethane. The reaction is shown below.  Since the heat of combustion of ethane is $\pu{-1560 kJ mol-1}$, how much heat is exchanged by the system if the reaction is the system?
$$\ce{C2H6 (g) + 7/2 O2 (g) -> 2 CO2 (g) + 3 H2O (g)}$$
express $q$ in $\pu{kJ}$.

The answer I keep getting is $\pu{1193 kJ}$ because $\frac{23}{30.07} \times (-1560)$ would be $-1193$ and we are meant to express heat as being positive so it would finally be 1193. This is wrong apparently. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $\Delta H$ is negative, the emitted heat is often taken as positive, according to some scientists studying combustions. Of course, it is contrary to the usual definition of thermodynamics.

Comment: At constant pressure, $\Delta H$ = q, so their signs are actually the same: If thermal energy flows out of the system the heat flow (q) is negative, and visa versa.  [Less precisely, you can think of it as: Heat lost by the system is negative, while heat gained by the system is positive—if you are defining heat flow relative to the system.]  If you think q always has to be positive, that would be (as you can see) incorrect.  If your teacher is telling you to always *report* q as positive, what they're asking for is not q, but |q| (the absolute value of q).  You should clarify this with them.

Comment: I have a slightly pedantic objection to the question: the "reaction" can't really be a "system", the set of all atoms that undergo the reaction might be a system.  We won't know how much heat is "exchanged" between the system and its surroundings without more information.  (Is this isothermal combustion or adiabatic?). Thus IMO the literal answer is `UNKNOWABLE`